# Understand setPresistanceEnabled(true) and keepSynced(true)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read a lot of questions and answers at StackOverflow but I didn't find the 100% words to answer my question.

***App Example:***
I have an Android application that uses Firebase Realtime Database. My MainActivity has a listener (ValueEventListener) to get "shops" from the database. Every time when I open my app MainActivity runs the same functions so the "shops" are downloaded from the database over and over.

**Please tell me:**
Is the "setPresistanceEnabled(true) is working that way -> When MainActivity is running and on my phone is cache of the database then "shops" are downloading from the database or not? (What if exists a difference between local cache of "shops" and "shops" from the database?)

***My goal:***
I want to reduce download data from Database.
I don't need to make the app working when my phone internet is offline. I just want to reduce download kb.

Sample of my code

```
// STORE ALL SHOPS IN TEMP ARRAY LIST
    DatabaseReference db_shops = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    db_shops.child("shops").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot allshopsSnapshot) {

            shopsList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot uid_shop : allshopsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Shop shop = new Shop();
                shop.setUid(String.valueOf(uid_shop.getKey()));
                shop.setCategory((String.valueOf(uid_shop.child("category").getValue())));
                shop.setCheckLocation((String.valueOf(uid_shop.child("checkLocation").getValue())));
                shop.setCode((String.valueOf(uid_shop.child("code").getValue())));
                shopsList.add(shop);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_appnotloaded);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time when I open my app MainActivity runs the same functions so the "shops" are downloaded from the database over and over.

When using "addValueEventListener()", it means that you are always in sync with the Firebase servers. We usually say that you are listening for real-time updates. This also means that every time something is changed in the database, the "onDataChange()" method is called and you get as an argument a DataSnapshot object that contains all the data that exists at the DatabaseReference at which you are pointing to. Even if there is, let's say, only one change in the database, you'll always get all the data within that node, including all sub-nodes. However, if you need to get the data only once, you should consider using [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query):

> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.

Regarding:

> Is the "setPresistanceEnabled(true)" is working in that way?

You should know that when using the above statement, it means that any data in your Firebase Realtime Database client will be synced as soon as the device gets network connectivity. So all that data will persist to disk and will be available while offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means that your app will work as it would be online by using the local data stored in the cache.

> What if exists a difference between the local cache of "shops" and "shops" from the database?

As said before, you always get fresh data from the Firebase servers.

> I want to reduce download data from Database. I don't need to make the app working when my phone's internet is offline. I just want to reduce download kb.

If you want to reduce the size of the downloaded data, you might consider getting it in smaller chunks. This technique is called pagination and it's used especially to download the data from the server progressively. Moreover, if you don't need to use the offline feature of the Firebase Realtime Database, you can simply disable this feature by using:

```
setPresistanceEnabled(false);
```

This means that won't be able to query your database if you are offline.